# c++ how to skip the call of parent's destructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, destructor

The problem below is not very common, so I can't find anything online that could be of help:

I have `class parent`, which **must** have the default constructor and destructor, I am not supposed to define anything about these two members.

I need to take control of `ptr` destruction, it must be destructed only if it is not referenced, which is controlled by `counter` in `someclass`.

```
class parent {
public:
   someclass * ptr;
}
class child: public parent {

   ~child() {                           //<-- this line
      cout<<"in ~child!"<<endl;
      if(this->ptr == NULL)  cout<<"ptr is NULL"<<endl;
      this->ptr->delete_reference();    //<-- here ptr = NULL
    }

    someclass* get_ptr() {
       return this->ptr;
    }
}

class someclass {
  void delete_reference() {
    counter--;
    if(counter == 0)   delete this;
}
```

The problem is that in `this line` parent's default destructor is called and does `ptr = NULL`, as a result, `ptr` is not properly destructed.

Is there a way to skip the call of ~parent with these restrictions?

I also tried to remove inheritance, and have an instance of `parent` in `child`, but the same thing happens, parent's destructor is called again.

Furthermore, I need `ptr` in `parent` because there are more child classes and they need to share this information.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
OK as I understood, I got something wrong here... the problem is how ptr gets NULL. 
As long as I confused the order of destructor calls, then the problem is not in `this line`.

```
void function() {
  child ch1;
  for(int i = 0; i<1; i++) {
    cout<<iterating<<endl; 
    do_some_work(ch1);
  }
  if(ch1->get_ptr() != NULL) cout<<"ptr is OK"<<endl;

  return;
  //Here is the destructor ~child called (?)
}

int main() {
  function();

}
```

The above calling is the way I use `child`. Inside `do_some_work` there is actually a lot of work that is difficult to describe here.

The point is that after `do_some_work` finishes, `ptr` is OK. Then I suppose destructors are called and `ptr` seems to be `NULL`.

So, the above will print:

```
iterating
ptr is OK
in child
ptr is NULL
Segmentation fault
```

Is there any explanation after this edit?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: `this->ptr` from the child-destructor is not valid regardless, as `ptr` is private to `parent`. You may want to revise that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I doubt his class is called `someclass` so this is probably an incorrect example.

Comment: yes, actually, the members are public, will edit this...

Comment: @SethCarnegie I concur, and as such was hoping the "revise" suggestion would be heeded to help accurately reflect what is *really* going on.

Comment: Can you modify someclass?

Comment: You are incorrect about the order of destruction. The child destructor is called **before** the parent destructor.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the access. Now the last thing I'm failing to understand. you say you need to "take control" of `ptr`, yet it is a class that self-destructs instances upon its own reference counting mechanics. And since your child destructor gets called prior to the base (`parent`) destructor, so long as `~parent()` invokes `ptr->delete_reference()` there is no problem. If parent is *known* not to do this, then `~child()` can, but `ptr` will be invalid once `~child()` is finished with it. If you don't *know* whether `~parent()` releases that thing or not, you are, in a word, screwed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > The problem is that in this line parent's default destructor is called

No.

> > and does ptr = NULL,

And No.

First, the parent's destructor (default or otherwise) is called *after* the child's, not before.

Second, the the parent's default destructor probably doesn't set `ptr` to `NULL`. It probably doesn't touch `ptr` at all. (I say "probably", because there is no way of knowing. Referencing `ptr` at all after the parent destructor returns is undefined behavior.)

I suggest that you have come to an incorrect conclusion. Please post a short complete program that demonstrates your problem and we can help you arrive at the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

1. You could easily check `if(ptr) ...` [or `if (this->ptr)` if you prefer].
2. This does seem rather "wrong". Not calling a base-class destructor is definitely not part of a normal class behaviour, and would make me think that the class hierarchy is wrong.

So, in summary, you are probably doing something wrong when you "need" to do this. Think about how your classes interact, and fix the fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

`delete`ing an object through a derived pointer is undefined behaviour if the parent's destructor is not virtual, so this code exhibits undefined behaviour.

Anyway, if the parent has no destructor defined then why are you concerned about not calling it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Isn't it virtual as long as it is the default destructor?

Comment: @KalliaChro no, you have to define one yourself.

Comment: @KalliaChro default destructor is not virtual

Comment: @KalliaChro also, the parent's destructor is called _after_ the derived classes, and it doesn't set `ptr` to `NULL`, so it's not your problem. It's getting set to  `NULL` somehow else.